Django URL 404 - 1 week spent debugging with GPT4, Claude luck. One specific function is just NOT resolving
Issue Summary:
I'm facing an issue where the /LS/mark-text-responses/ URL in my Django application is not being found when an AJAX request is sent to the mark_text_responses view. This issue is occurring in the user-facing part of my application, specifically in the JavaScript code that sends the AJAX request. I'm receiving a 404 Not Found error, indicating that the URL is not being resolved correctly.
Relevant JavaScript Code:
**javascript
**

function submitWorksheet(event, activityIndex) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const worksheetForm = event.target;
    const worksheetQuestionsData = worksheetForm.querySelector('.worksheet-questions').textContent;
    let worksheetData = {};
    try {
        worksheetData = JSON.parse(worksheetQuestionsData);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error parsing worksheet data:', error);
        return;
    }
    // ... (code omitted for brevity) ...
    if (question.type === 'text_response') {
        const textResponse = worksheetForm.querySelector(`textarea[name="response_${index + 1}"]`).value;
        const feedbackElement = document.getElementById(`text-response-feedback-${index + 1}`);
        // Make an AJAX request to the server to get feedback on the text response
        fetch('/lessons/mark-text-responses/', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'X-CSRFToken': document.querySelector('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').value
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                activity_id: '{{ activity.id }}',
                question_index: index,
                text_response: textResponse
            })
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            if (data.feedback) {
                feedbackElement.textContent = data.feedback;
            } else {
                console.error('Error:', data.error);
                feedbackElement.textContent = 'Error processing text responses.';
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error:', error);
            feedbackElement.textContent = 'Error processing text response.';
        });
    }
}



Relevant Python / Django code:
python


# LM/urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    # ...
    path('mark-text-responses/', views.mark_text_responses, name='mark_text_responses'),
    # ...
]



LM/views.py
def mark_text_responses(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Process the request
        # ...
        return JsonResponse({'error': 'Invalid request method'}, status=400)

What We Know for Sure:
The /LS/mark-text-responses/ URL pattern is correctly defined in the LM/urls.py file.
The mark_text_responses view is defined in the LM/views.py file.
The Django server is running, and other URLs are accessible.
The AJAX request is being sent from the JavaScript code, including the CSRF token in the request headers.

I AM STUMPED.
On the front-end, there's a button that says "submit worksheet". Nothing happens in terms of functionality except the py console shows 404 :(
Steps Tried:
Checked the URL pattern in the LM/urls.py file to ensure the /LS/mark-text-responses/ URL is correctly defined.
Verified the mark_text_responses view in the LM/views.py file.
Tried debugging the Django server by adding print statements to the mark_text_responses view.
Attempted to access the /LS/mark-text-responses/ URL directly in the browser.

Expected:
Expected calling the submit worksheet function to do anythign other than return a 404...
Steps Tried:
Checked the URL pattern in the LM/urls.py file to ensure the /LS/mark-text-responses/ URL is correctly defined.
Verified the mark_text_responses view in the LM/views.py file.
Tried debugging the Django server by adding print statements to the mark_text_responses view.
Attempted to access the /LS/mark-text-responses/ URL directly in the browser.

Expected:
Expected calling the submit worksheet function to do anythign other than return a 404...
Edit #1 - Full Relevant Console Log
[02/May/2024 16:06:01] "POST /mark-text-responses/ HTTP/1.1" 404 4427
Not Found: /mark-text-responses/
[02/May/2024 16:06:02] "POST /mark-text-responses/ HTTP/1.1" 404 4427


Your ajax is fetching '/lessons/mark-text-responses/ but you continually refer to '/LS/mark-text-responses/.  If these are supposed to be equivalent, can you show the URLs file that makes this happen, likely the top level urls.py file.

Yep these are equivalent I renamed lessons to LS in this post to hide some details but clearly missed one. I have confirmed the top level urls.py files is fine, as other functions work.

Just for completeness sake, can you please provide the full 404 error from py console or network tab.

The URL that is not being found is /mark-text-responses not /LS/mark-text-responses or anything similar.  If this is only being referenced in your fetch() method, double check the URL there.
